Do we need the tag tools?
I just came across the tag tools. This tag seems very unspecific to me. Because in the end one can tag nearly every question with this tag. So I would vote to delete it or merge it with some more appropriate. What is your opinion here?

Nowadays, the tools tag is no longer strictly used for tool recommendations. It occasionally accompanies general tool questions, a couple of examples: 1, 2, 3, 4. I've even sinned so myself partially because the unclarity of this tag.
I think we should edit the tag's name and wiki to make it clear that this tag should be used for general tool discussion and recommendations, and not used when a specific tool tag is more applicable.
As usual, I'll act upon it if this answer is upvoted.

I think the tag is necessary at this point. If you look at the questions, it is being used only when asking for tool recommendations (7 of 7 questions). We could replace it with tool-recommendations similar to the software recommendations tag on AskUbuntu. 
However, if this consistent usage does persist throughout beta, then I dont think there is any need to replace the tag.
